# XCode GET POST WebServer

Tags: html, objective-c, webserver, nsurlrequest

I'm beginner from Xcode. I have to do an application that get and send data from embedded webserver that I designed in  a microcontroller  MICROCHIP.
Now I'm able to get information from webserver ( In my webserver I have a `/status.xml` file where I have all the dynamic variables)

Now I am not able to click a button. The HTML code to click a button is

```
onmousedown="newAJAXCommand('buttons.cgi?btn=1')"
```

In my webserver I have a file `buttons.cgi`.

My target is designed a button in Xcode that he does this action

I tried to use `NSMutableURLRequest` class and `SetHTTPMethod:@"GET"` or `@"POST"` but this code doesn't work

```
    NSString *post = @"btn=1";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES ];
    NSString *Get_lenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSURL *serviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebserver.com/buttons.cgi?"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *serviceRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceURL];
    [serviceRequest setValue:Get_lenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [serviceRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Comment: do you mean your codes work in web page but not in Xcode ? Are you working on iOS or Mac OS X ?

Comment: Hi, I'm working in IOS, I'm developing IPAD application.

Comment: Hi , I said that the webserver is working good and if I acces to webserver via Safari is working good, the problem is that when I acces via IPAD Simulator XCode , I'm not able to do work a button correctly with the code that I wrote

Comment: You never send the `serviceRequest` you need something like ` NSData *dataContent = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];`. `dataContent` being the result of your request. This is a very simple version of something that can be made to look a lot better but it was off the top of my head.

Comment: Btw: it's Xcode ... Not XCode or xCode .... ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple errors in the codes:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES ];
```

Why don't you use UTF-8 ?

```
NSString *Get_lenght = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
[serviceRequest setValue:Get_lenght forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
```

You can't set `Content-Type` as an integer.

Last, you didn't send out the `NSMutableURLRequest`. To send out the request, use :

```
NSString *response;
NSError *error;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

where `response` will contain the response data, if you need it; and the `error` will contain error during request & response, if there is any error.

Comment: Hello, I used a code that I found in this forum, I think that it's correct! Could you tell how do I do to send this action correctly. I have to send to webserver "http://mywebserver.com/buttons.cgi?btn=1".

Comment: HI, I used your suggestion  and I wrote in my Xcode application:

Comment: HI, I used your suggestion and I wrote in my Xcode application:

NSURLRequest *serviceURL1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebserver/buttons.cgi?btn=8"]];
    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:serviceURL1 returningResponse:Nil error:Nil];


And now the button is working
Thank you for your collaboration
Fabio